# Form GET method not showing content

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm working on a FAQ page, and I'm trying to have one page instead of creating multiple .html files with the questions and answers. I have a post.php which contains the id & questions and answers + the html page in the same .php file.

This is the post.php file

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];

if ($id == "1") {
   $question = "Question1";
   $answer = "Answer";
} elseif ($id == "2") {
   $question = "Question2";
   $answer = "Answer";
} elseif ($id == "3") {
   $question = "Question3";
   $answer = "Answer";
}
else {
   $question = "Error";
   $answer = "Question ID doesn't exist.";
}
?>
```

and I have this in the post.php file under the `<!DOCTYPE html>` thing

```
<h2 id="content"><?php echo $question ?></h2>
<p><?php echo $answer ?></p>
```

Whenever I open the page, it doesn't show anything, the page is completely blank..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gk6j7.png (screenshot)

```
**EDIT: I FIXED THE SCRIPT, WORKS NOW**
```

Comment: why all those exit statements ? just remove them :-)

Comment: Remove the "exit;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove the **exit** and you will get it working
The exit function makes you exit the script
And here you are quitting before you even print something

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is not with $_GET, remove you exit statement from if conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds dumb, but have you tried to remove the exit()?

Answer (score 0):

Further explanation:

The [exit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) function terminates a script completely, the code that is ran beforehand the call is terminated also hence why your page is blank.

What you would be looking for is calling `exit();` instead of `exit;` to keep the code ran before the function is called.

From the look of your code, just do as other answers have said and remove the [exit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) function calls.

They are not needed because once one of the if-else statements are satisfied then your script will end itself.